# How to avoid scan or filter a specific directory in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, filter, directory, spring-integration

With Spring integration, I would like to use my inbound channel adapter to scan a directory with a tree structure like this:

```
INDICATOR/
    ref_1/
        INPUTS/
        ERRORS/
    ref_2/
        INPUTS/
        ERRORS/
```

My root directory will be `INDICATOR` I would like to recursively scan all the directory and get all the files in, exept the ones in the `ERRORS` directory. In other words, how to *deny* or *avoid* scanning this specific directory?

is it possible to implements this class `org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner` and add a specific filter?

This is my actual config

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="csvInputChannel"
    directory="file:${directory.input}"
    prevent-duplicates="false"
    auto-startup="true" 
    auto-create-directory="false" 
    queue-size="1"
    scanner="dirScanner">

    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" default="true" fixed-rate="1000" receive-timeout="5000" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="dirScanner" 
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner" />
```

Actually, I can only scan ALL the files present in ALL the directory recursively, I don' thave a clue how to add a filter.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I don't issues really to implement your own `RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner`:

```
public class SkipErrorDirRecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner extends RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner {

   protected File[] listEligibleFiles(File directory) throws IllegalArgumentException {
       if (!"ERRORS".equals(directorygetName())) {
           return super.listEligibleFiles(directory);
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, doesn't really work, but it helps me to get on the right way!! see below

Answer (score 1):

I find a better way to do it, I just extend the `DefaultDirectoryScanner` and use this function

```
public class SkipErrorDirRecursive extends DefaultDirectoryScanner{
    protected File[] listEligibleFiles(File directory) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        File[] rootFiles = directory.listFiles();
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(rootFiles.length);
        for (File rootFile : rootFiles) {
            if (rootFile.isDirectory()) {
                if (!"ERRORS".equals(rootFile.getName()))
                    files.addAll(Arrays.asList(listEligibleFiles(rootFile)));
            }
            else {
                files.add(rootFile);
            }
        }
        return files.toArray(new File[files.size()]);
    }
}
```